# Homebrew installed PostgreSQL for use by multiple accounts

Tags: permission, homebrew, network-user, postgresql

I'm using Homebrew to install PostgreSQL (PG) on a MacBook Air.

`admin` user `brew install`ed PostgreSQL.

I'd like another (mobile account) user to be able to use the database for Rails development. `admin` is owner of `/usr/local/` but `mobile` user is member of a group that has rwx permission. `brew doctor` is happy and mobile user can successfully `brew install`

How best to set up permissions for this to work?

for instance, running `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8` from the `admin` account created a database for the admin user. And, now it would seem, it wants PG to be launched by that admin user.

I'd really like either a neutral account to launch PG process *or* ideally the mobile account to be able to launch and quit an instance of PG as needed.

Point being PG doesn't need to be running ALL the time (LaunchDaemon). Ideally, it's a LaunchAgent in mobile user's account.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

According to the postgres output, you need to run the postgres server as the same user that creates the database with initdb.

```
mr-clean:~ smurf$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "smurf".
This user must also own the server process.
```

That means the same user will need to launch the postgres server process. Other users will still be able to launch the client and connect to it, though. So you just need to do the "admin" tasks - setup and daemon control - with that owner account.

If you want to do everything with the one `mobile` account, then just run `initdb` as `mobile` instead of as `admin` after doing the `brew install postgresql` as normal. (It's not who you `brew install` as that matters, it's who you `initdb` as.) This'll create the database, and `rwx` permissions on `/usr/local/var` (not `/usr/local`) will be enough to allow this. Then do all your PG work as `mobile`. The LaunchAgent should work with this approach, though I haven't tested it.

To allow multiple users to effectively manage the postgres server (launch and stop the daemon), set it up basically the same way, with a dedicated `postgres` (or `mobile`) account that both does the initial `initdb` and brings the server up or down. Then create a little script to `ssh` in to `localhost` as `postgres` and run the command to bring the server up or down with the same command you'd use in the single-user case. And set up ssh keys so that all the accounts you want to manage PG can ssh in as `postgres` (that is, cat their public keys to postgres' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file). Now you can effectively have multiple users manage Postgres without deviating from the dedicated-daemon-user model that Postgres expects and fiddling with file permissions and so on.

This ssh technique works for any service that needs to be controlled by a dedicated account, and will generalize to the case where you're running your things on different machines.